# How to use choice keys in l3?

Tags: xparse, l3keys, l3fp

I want to create some shortcuts for constants and I want to use these shortcuts for

- calculations (without units) for example with \fpeval
- with one or two different units

I tried the following code, but I dont understand really the use of choice-keys and the the use of the value for calculations with \fpeval do not work.

Thanks for help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \numSc } { O{3} m } {
 \num[scientific-notation=true,round-mode=figures,round-precision=#1] { \fp_eval:n { #2 } } 
 }

\keys_define:nn { thomas/elC }
 {
  dez .int_set:N = \l__thomas_test_dez_int,
  dez .initial:n = 4,
  unit .choice:,
  unit / choice-As .code:n = { \ampere\second },
  unit / choice-C .code:n = { \coulomb },
%  unit .initial:n = As,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand { \elC } { s O{} } { 
  \group_begin:
   \keys_set:nn { thomas/elC } { #2 }
   \IfBooleanTF {#1}
    { 
    \SI [scientific-notation=true,round-mode=figures,round-precision=\l__thomas_test_dez_tl] 
    { 1.6021766209e-19 } { \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_int } 
    }
    { \num [scientific-notation=true,round-mode=figures,round-precision=\l__thomas_test_dez_int] { 1.6021766209e-19 } }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\elCh{1.6021766209e-19}

\begin{document}

\numSc[6]{ 3*\elCh }

\elC*[dez=5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? For me it does compile. What is your real question?

Comment: @TeXnician yes this code compiles, but I want to have the units. Sometimes  As or C. And this does not work

Comment: Btw: You do not need to load `xfp`, `siunitx` suffices. Do also note that you do not want to do an `int_set` on a variable you name like a token list, make it `_int` instead.

Comment: And use the command for calculations does not work too.

Comment: Which command does not work? `\fp_eval` does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following does work by introducing a variable that holds the unit. If you set a key you cannot use a direct value, but have to use some intermediate form.

[image: values]

Some further improvements:

- You do not need `xfp`, `siunitx` suffices.
- You should name an integer like an integer, not like a token list (`_int` instead of `_tl`).
- If you set an initial value, it must have been defined as a choice.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \numSc } { O{3} m } {
 \num[scientific-notation=true,round-mode=figures,round-precision=#1] { \fp_eval:n { #2 } } 
 }

\tl_new:N \l__thomas_unit_tl
\keys_define:nn { thomas/elC }
 {
  dez .int_set:N = \l__thomas_dez_int,
  dez .initial:n = 4,
  unit .choice:,
  unit / choice-As .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l__thomas_unit_tl { \ampere\second } },
  unit / choice-C .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l__thomas_unit_tl { \coulomb } },
  unit .initial:n = choice-As,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand { \elC } { s O{} } { 
  \group_begin:
   \keys_set:nn { thomas/elC } { #2 }
   \IfBooleanTF {#1}
    { 
    \SI [scientific-notation=true,round-mode=figures,round-precision=\l__thomas_dez_int] 
    { 1.6021766209e-19 } { \tl_use:N \l__thomas_unit_tl } 
    }
    { \num [scientific-notation=true,round-mode=figures,round-precision=\l__thomas_dez_int] { 1.6021766209e-19 } }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\elCh{1.6021766209e-19}

\begin{document}

\numSc[6]{ 3*\elCh }

\elC*[dez=5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: -@TeXnician thanks this works fine. And thanks for your improvements.